# "itectec.com" website links — could they be stripped from questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

The website at the ***itectec.com*** domain is stealing content from StackExchange sites (including this one) and other forums and shows it as their own content.

They are pretty good with search engines, the website often pops up in the search results next to or before the original, legit hoster of the content.

I don't know what's the business behind running this scam site, but I for one don't want to wait until it becomes malicious / a source of malware.

Could we implement a filter that would strip links to that domain from questions and answers?

(Optimally users attempting to paste these links could be warned about the problem with the site.)

---

Maybe *practice extra care* with the site in question:

I'm no expert or anything, but as soon as I have opened that website in Firefox, a steady amount of disk write started up (exposed real time by gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor), and maintained itself until I rebooted. (Upon shutdown even a 90 seconds "stop job" timeout has shown up, delaying the shutdown, that I have cut short with a REISUB.)

I don't know if it had anything to do with the site or whether it was a coincidence.

---

**Update:**

I have learned about the existence of StackExchange's "SmokeDetector": [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically)

*I think setting up SmokeDetector to assist in the case this question introduces could be relevant.*

Since the suggested canonical answer (the one this was marked as duplicate of):

- is 2-3 years *older* than the info about SmokeDetector (allowing one to speculate that the info about SmokeDetector (or about its level of efficiency) was not available at that time)
- and is promoting a possibly inferior manual procedure

I vote to not delete this question, but to consider a more up-to-date answer to it (involving SmokeDetector).

Comment: @Dan Thank you, I have used the contact form with the "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" template, as prescribed in your second link.

Comment: Voters: This does not need to be reopened or deleted.  Simply go through Ask Ubuntu posts where this site shows up and remove them from the posts, or flag the posts for moderator attention.

Comment: But we seem to have a machine for that...